# Aliasing columns in web2py JOIN query

Tags: data-access-layer, web2py

I'm joining two tables with identical column names, and aliasing the column name like so:

```
row = db().select(db.member.id,db.member.name,db.group.name.with_alias('group_name'),
        left=db.member.on(db.member.id==db2.group.member_id))
```

But this still gives me a key error, as if I hadn't aliased the column at all:

```
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: Can you post your data model for member and group? Also, you use "db.group.name.with_alias" but you use "db2.group.member_id" in your join condition... is this the same 'group' table?